# Polymer Elements ShadowDOM child nodes - Setting style attributes dynamically

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I'd like some ideas on how to set a `font-size` to a `<paper-textarea>`, dynamically (i.e set `font-size` from JS instead of CSS).

- There's no default attribute in the docs for font-size.
- It looks like it can only be set via a mixin (which cannot be changed via JS).

For example, `<paper-textarea>`'s DOM tree looks something like this:

- `<paper-textarea>`

  - ShadowDOM begins
  - `<div>`
  - `<div>`
  - `<div>`
  - `<textarea>` <-- This is the actual textarea

> Is there any way to target the child-node in it's shadowDOM via JS and set it's style directly?

An example, which of course doesn't work.

- I bind property `fontSize` to the `<paper-textarea>`
- Since there's no attribute `fontSize` to set for this particular element, it doesn't work.

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
<link href="paper-input/paper-textarea.html" rel="import">
<link href="paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="x-example">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
      max-width: 320px;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
      <paper-textarea label="Textarea" value="{{inputData}}" font-size="{{fontSize}}"></paper-textarea>
    <paper-button class="primary" on-tap="incrementFontSize">Increment Font Size</paper-button>
  </template>
<script>
  HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
    "use strict";

    Polymer({

      is: "x-example",
      properties: {
       inputData: {
          type: String,
          value: "Hello World"
        },
        
        fontSize: {
          type: Number,
          value: 16
        }
      },
      
      incrementFontSize: function() {
        this.set("fontSize", this.fontSize + 4);  
      }

    });
  });
</script>

</dom-module>

<x-example></x-example>
```

Ideally, I would set up a `fontSize` observer and imperatively target the `<paper-textarea>`'s child node to set it's style when `fontSize` changes.

How can I target those nodes?

**Note:** I'd prefer an "official" way, if it exists. The Polymer spec changes often and flimsy hacks would tend to break when updating the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
<dom-module id="dynamic-style">
 <template>
  <style>
   :host{
    --myfont:10px; 
   }
  paper-textarea{
    --paper-input-container-input:{
     font-size:var(--my-font);
   };
 }
 </style>
 <paper-textarea on-tap="updateStyle"></paper-textarea>
</template>
</dom-module>
<script>
 Polymer({
  is:"dynamic-style",
   properties:{
    fontSize:{
     type:Number,
     value:10
    }
   },
   updateStyle:function(){
    var style={'--my-font':this.computeFont()+'px'}
    this.updateStyles(style);
   },
   computeFont:function(){
    return this.fontSize+=4;
   }
 })
</script>
```

Dynamic styling is currently an issue with `Polymer` and as per recommendation `updateStyles` is the only method through which it will work.

And here's a working snippet based on your example:

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
<link href="paper-input/paper-textarea.html" rel="import">
<link href="paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="x-example">
  <style is="custom-style">
    :host {
      display: block;
      max-width: 320px;
    }
    :root {
      --font-size: 12px;
      --paper-input-container-input: {
        font-size: var(--font-size);
      }
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <paper-textarea label="Textarea" value="{{inputData}}"></paper-textarea>
    <paper-button class="primary" on-tap="incrementFontSize">Increment Font Size</paper-button>
  </template>
  <script>
    HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
      "use strict";

      Polymer({

        is: "x-example",
        properties: {
          inputData: {
            type: String,
            value: "Hello World"
          },

          fontSize: {
            type: Number,
            value: 16
          }
        },

        incrementFontSize: function() {
          var style = {
            '--font-size': this.computeFont() + 'px'
          }
          this.updateStyles(style);
        },

        computeFont: function() {
          return this.fontSize += 4;
        }

      });
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>

<x-example></x-example>
```

Comment: That did it, thanks :) - Hope you don't mind that I've edited your post to include a working snippet as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can use plain javascript in your polymer, simply write

```
this.style.fontSize = Number(this.fontSize + 4)+"px"
```

Comment: **No**, this won't work - the actual `<textarea>` in `<paper-textarea` is encapsulated in it's ShadowDOM, thus this won't have any effect, thus why I ask the question :)